# Are there any ways to send multiples headers in one HTTP request using Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, httprequest

I try to make a HTTP POST request that contains multiple headers using Angular 2, but the data I post present null in my backend API, and when I modify my header as this:

```
{
'X-API-KEY': authToken,
'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
'roomName':roomName,
'locationOrCommand':locationOrCommand
}
```

the request is never shows up in API. 
However, when I only have one header in the request, like this:

```
{'X-API-KEY': authToken}
```

my api can get the that one data (authtoken),
I already test the swagger and postman for my backend API, it works fine.
What should i do how?

I tried several ways for constructing the header, like:

1. `{ headers: new HttpHeaders().append('X-API-KEY', authToken).append('roomName',roomName).append('locationOrCommand',locationOrCommand).append('Content-Type', 'text/plain')}`
2. `{ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-API-KEY', authToken).set('roomName',roomName).set('locationOrCommand',locationOrCommand).set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')}`
3. `{ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-API-KEY', authToken).append('roomName',roomName).append('locationOrCommand',locationOrCommand).set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')}`

I except my API can get the data that post from front end.

Comment: Do you need these headers on every request, or only some requests?

Comment: only on one request

Answer (score 1):

HttpHeaders is immutable so when you call append or set it returns the new object.

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();
let other_header = header.append('foo','23');
console.log(header.get('foo')); // output null
console.log(other_header.get('foo')) // output 23
```

**We have an example :**

First, immutability for data sent over the wire is a common pattern in other platforms, too — one example is the OkHttp client in the Android/Java world.

Second, when sending data over the wire, we let it go over the boundary of our application and enter it into a remote system. Once data has crossed that boundary, it’s published to the world and out of ‘our’ control. By chance, we like data objects in our application to reflect what will be sent in the future or what has been received in the past. To achieve that, we need immutables. Think of it the other way round: when a request has been sent and the request body has been serialized, and after that, we’d modify a request body object, then data locally held in the client diverges from data sent to remote. It will — at some time — turn out to be the cause of silly and avoidable bugs.

I have not found documentation or a talk form the OkHttp authors why they chose immutables. However, the Angular documentation — to my surprise — says quite a lot about the design choice for immutables!